# XCode error in saving storyboards on NTFS drive

Tags: xcode, ntfs

I am a beginner trying to learn XCode. Recently, I installed [NTFS-3G](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G) so that I can write on my external NTFS drive.

I created a new project in XCode and I am having a problem saving the project storyboard. I get the error:

The document "Main.storyboard" could not be saved.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdcmm.png)

I can write with no problems on the folder in my NTFS drive and I wonder why XCode has this error. I also tried moving some of my old projects inside the NTFS drive but I also get this error. But when I move them back to the Mac OS drive, it works fine again.

I am using XCode 7.3.1 on El Capitan (10.11.5) (I have not upgraded both softwares yet).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.